# How to add authentication to API Platform with external OpenID provider (OAuth2)

Tags: authentication, symfony, oauth-2.0, jwt, api-platform.com

I am working on a project with **Symfony** 6 as a backend and **React** as a frontend. I've implemented the **OAuth2** authentication login and configured API Platform and exposed the endpoints for React.

`API Platform` has a good ***JWT***  implementation guide which helps to use JWT token authentication with username and password.

But how can I authenticate User on Symfony with add `OAuth2` authentication to ***API Platform*** with (external OpenID provider) Azure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific controller for that, with a route that triggers your external openId auth then returns an api-platform generated JWT.